# iOS: displaying filename once file is selected

Tags: objective-c

I have a table cell which, once clicked, opens the file browser and lets me select a file to be uploaded to a server. The problem is, I'm unable to find a way to display the name of whatever was selected. For now, I just display "file selected" and do the upload, but I'd really like to be able to display the file name. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

well, not knowing exactly how you do what you are doing, all i can say is, if you use the NSString object that represents the url/path of the object you can use

`NSString *name = [objectURL lastPathComponent];`